# Date Between (Start & Now)

Tags: sql, presto

Not sure how to use the `NOW()` function in presto. Seems like it should be straight forward, but i'm getting no luck

```
SELECT DISTINCT field
FROM table
WHERE field BETWEEN '2019-01-01' and NOW()
```

*field = varchar*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should match data types to avoid implicit conversions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field
FROM table
WHERE CAST(field AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE '2019-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE;
```

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT field
FROM table
WHERE DATE(field) BETWEEN DATE '2019-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: `DATE '2019-01-01'` is the syntax for date literals. (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html). You don't need a cast or `date` function for that.